# Atualizar data a cada update em uma tabela

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Possuo uma tabela `pessoa`. Nela eu tenho um campo chamado `pe_modified` que tem como objetivo ter a data da última modificação na tabela.

Ao invés de eu ter de atualizar na consulta, é possível ser automático ? 
Existe algum tipo de campo ou um valor *default* que atualiza a hora sempre que é realizado um update na tabela?

Comment: Já viu falar em triggers? Veja: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

A função `now()` retorna a data atual. Uma maneira de automatizar esse mecanismo é utilizando uma *trigger* como a do código abaixo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_pe_modified_column()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
   NEW.pe_modified = now(); 
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER update_pessoa_pe_modified 
BEFORE UPDATE ON pessoa
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
update_pe_modified_column();
```

**Fonte:** [Automatically updating a timestamp column in PostgreSQL](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2006/aug/04/automatically-updating-a-timestamp-column-in-postgresql/)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Para atualizar campos antes ou depois de eventos, é necessário criar uma trigger.

Abaixo um exemplo de trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_update_conhecimento()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO conta_corrente
    (descricao, data, fg_debito, valor, numero)
    VALUES
    ('CONHECIMENTO GERADO', CURRENT_DATE, true, NEW.frete_peso + NEW.frete_km, NEW.numero);

    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_conhecimento
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON conhecimento
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_update_conhecimento();
```

A trigger acima faz um insert na tabela conta_corrente após a execução de um update na tabela conhecimento.

Comment: Creio que esta resposta seria mais útil se você desse um exemplo referente as tabelas/colunas citadas pelo @Jonathan.